# How to use mesh surface height for shading nodes?

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes, shaders, shader-nodes

I want to make the color of my mesh change according to the global height of my original mesh (it is rigged) using shader nodes. I’m looking for a way of obtaining the height of all points on the mesh in 3d space and inputing it to a color ramp node. I don’t want to change the UV map because I already have other shaders on that object. Does anyone know how to do this? I can use basic geo nodes but would prefer not to.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable *Add Rest Position* under `Mesh Properties > Shape Keys`. Then, use it in your shader as needed. It's called `rest_position`.

[image: Setup]

Even if you're using a few UV maps for your material setups, you can add one more for other needs. I wouldn't rule out this option.

Comment: Thank you! this worked great :) I also didn't know I could have multiple UV maps for one object, thanks for the clarification

Comment: You're welcome!